Asking for suggestions / ideas / help for my project
My company assigned me a project where we have to create a saas of an existing system software.
basically the software takes a data file and an input format. then it generate receipts with the format we selected and data in it. i think the end users could use this as an SaaS receipt generation software.
when i opened those formats its designed on excel. i can see columns and headers etc. in the format file
this is not a normal kind of project. could anyone tell me how to do this step by step. what all technologies .
user story - i am a sales manager. i opened this site. i feed it a .xls of 1000 transactions of a month. i select a format provided and generate reports / receipts .
no idea where to start
report file sample
sample format file

To try to help clarify what steps to take, here are my questions.

Is the file you open with the data generated by existing software?
Should you generate reports with that file?


@rbarbeitor  the file that i can input (data file ) is of .xls format which contains rows of data. format files are already provded in the system software and looks like the image added above

Convert your xls file to csv and you will have the column headers on the first line and a tuple with all the values of each operation on the second line. You can convert that data to json, for example, and then use it to generate calculations, graphs, etc
